# Как переставить слова в тексте с помощью Python?

Tags: python

Есть задача:
Существует текстовый файл. Предположим, "Список.txt".
В этом списке записаны ФИО таким образом:

```
Рыжиков Константин Константинович
Шевченко Диана Дмитриевна
Соколова Елизавета Андреевна
Денисов Иван Павлович
```

И т.д.
Нужно:

1. С каждой строчки убрать отчество
2. Переставить фамилию и имя

Алгоритмически я понимаю, что нужно открыть файл и работать с его текстом. Но практическую реализацию не представляю.
Знаю, что в Python возможно создать список по разделителю, в нашем случае это " ". Но как это может помочь и может ли, не представляю.
Наведите на верный путь решения этой задачи.
Заранее благодарен!

Answer (score 3):

Судя по вашему вопросу, вы мало знакомы даже с основами языка python, поэтому я не уверен, что приведенные здесь ответы вам помогут.

```
res = []
with open(r'Список.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fn:
    for line in fn:
        res.append("{1} {0}".format(*(line.split(" "))))

print(res)
```

> ['Константин Рыжиков', 'Диана Шевченко', 'Елизавета Соколова', 'Иван Денисов']
>   ​

Comment: format(*(line.split(" ")) - красиво!

Answer (score -1):

Во-первых разделите текст `text = text.split()`, вы получите массив. И создаете новый пустой массив для измененного текста `ar_edited = []`

Далее создаёте цикл `for i in range(, len(text) - 3, 3):`, в нём каждая итерация будет обрабатывать одно ФИО.

В этом цикле уже обрабатываете то, что нужно:

```
ar_edited.append(text[i + 1] + text[i])
```

В новый массив добавляется имя и фамилия(порядок изменён, а отчества нет)

Чтобы перезаписать все, то достаточно пройтись по новому массиву, каждый элемент которого будет содержать одну строку с ИФ